# Make Firefox installed system wide automatically update itself - security implications

Tags: debian, firefox

I want to install Firefox system wide on Debian. Since it isn't installed using `apt` it needs to update itself. If I just extract the tarball in some system location it will fail to update due to insufficient permissions while running as user.

The tarball includes a binary called `updater` which I assume does the upgrades. Is it a good idea to give it the SUID bit so it runs as root while the browser runs as a user?